# Full low-level backup and restore

Tags: backup

I've got some embedded system running Android. Before I start compiling anything for it I'd like to do full backup and then have possibility to restore it. The only way of backup everything I know is to use:

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/dev/block/mmcblk1
```

but how to restore it when something went wrong and system is not running?
Is it possible to burn back this image to Android system - for example using fastboot?
I've got development board with Qualcomm MSM8909.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can restore all partitions grabbed by `dd` like this:

```
fastboot -w flashall
```

Or write separate partitions by

```
fastboot flash boot

fastboot flash recovery

fastboot flash userdata
```

Prior to that your should put your partitions to the same directory where you run fastboot. Separate partitions can be obtained by simple unpack of the image got from your `dd` command.